# Bonded Horncrest and Prey Upon interaction

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Prey Upon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrey%20Upon%5d) is used on [Bonded Horncrest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBonded%20Horncrest%5d), will it be able to "attack alone" ?
Is this the same for Bonded Horncrest being the target of [Savage Stomp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSavage%20Stomp%5d) and the [Cherished Hatchling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCherished%20Hatchling%5d)'s ability?

p.s. If Prey Upon is used on [Snapping Sailback](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnapping%20Sailback%5d), will it get a +1/+1 counter? and I assume the +1/+1 counter enters after the fight/dmg has been dealt, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If Prey Upon is used on Bonded Horncrest, will it be able to "attack alone"?

No, it won't. [Prey Upon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrey%20Upon%5d) is a spell that makes creatures *fight* each other. *Fight* is a keyword:

> 701.12. Fight
>
> > 701.12a A spell or ability may instruct a creature to fight another creature or it may instruct two creatures to fight each other. Each of those creatures deals damage equal to its power to the other creature.

I assume you got confused by the wording on the cards, but fighting has absolutely nothing to do with the combat phase. If a creature (such as [Bonded Horncrest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBonded%20Horncrest%5d)) cannot attack alone, it means that it cannot be the only creature declared as an attacker in the "declare attackers" step of the combat phase.

> p.s. If Prey Upon is used on Snapping Sailback, will it get a +1/+1 counter?

Assuming [Snapping Sailback](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnapping%20Sailback%5d) survives the damage it was dealt, then yes, it gets a +1/+1 counter.

> and I assume the +1/+1 counter enters after the fight/dmg has been dealt, right?

That's correct.

Comment: So will Bonded Horncrest be able to fight when Prey Upon (or Cherised Hatchling ability) is used on it? Even though it's the only creature (of your own *edit) to fight in that moment. Since it's "fighting" and not "attacking or blocking".

Comment: Yes. As I said, _fighting_ and _attacking_ are two different mechanics. A creature that cannot attack for any reason (maybe it has Defender or it has been enchanted by Faith's Fetters) can still fight other creatures.

Comment: No problem at all, friend. Glad I could help. I suggest you take some time to read through the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020180413.pdf) if you're a new player. You don't need to read all of it, but the "General" rule of each rule section will give you a good grasp of what that section is about, and it'll surely improve your general understanding of the game's mechanics.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @J.Salle, if you are a new player, you should read the Basic Rules:  http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf  The comprehensive rules are for later....

Comment: Yes, there's also the Basic Rules! They're indeed a better resource for a newer player to read. Thanks John!